# Can I use a ternary operator with only one result?

Tags: ruby

Will I run into any problems using a statement like this:

```
options[:discount] ? "Does something if true" : nil
```

Instead of:

```
"Do something if true" if options[:discount]
```

I'm not sure I would actually use the former syntax, but I am interested if returning `nil` in such a statement would cause any issues. Just trying to learn more about Ruby's structure and this was an interesting question to me. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Since `"Do something if true" if false #=> nil`, yes, they are equivalent, but the first is certainly clearer.

Comment: Ahh OK, that makes sense. So the second expression, if false, is really returning that same thing as the first, just without making it very clear that it's doing so. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Most of the time when coding we have lots of choices in how we do something, so we code for efficiency, and maintainability/readability. Part of the maintainability/readability is whether code clearly explains what it's doing, that there are no gotchas or hidden traps. Using a ternary statement as you suggested fails if you are only intending to do something on a true. Write code as if you're going to have to maintain it at 3AM after drinking. Or as if your code-partner is an 800lb ill-tempered gorilla who you'll have to explain your code to... after they were up at 3AM.

Comment: Don't forget sometimes `options[:discount] && "Something"` is good enough. It depends on the possible values `options[:discount]` might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may depend how you use it.

Let's try it with

```
options = {
  :discount => true
}

x = options[:discount] ? "Does something if true" : nil
y = "Do something if true" if options[:discount] 

p x
p y
```

and you get

```
"Does something if true"
"Do something if true"
```

With the `false`-value, you get two times `nil`.

If you want to print the result immediate, without an additional variable like in

```
p options[:discount] ? "Does something if true" : nil
p "Do something if true" if options[:discount]
```

you get the same result for `true`, but with `false`you get only one `nil`.The `if`-clause is used for the complete expression `p "Do something if true"`.

---

Or another example:

You can use the ternary operator as a parameter:

```
def my_method(par)
  p par
end
my_method(options[:discount] ? "Does something if true" : nil)
```

but you get `syntax error, unexpected modifier_if, expecting ')'` with

```
my_method("Do something if true" if options[:discount])
```

You can use the `if` with two braces:

```
my_method(("Do something if true" if options[:discount]))
```

or you use

```
my_method(if options[:discount]; "Do something if true";end )
```

Comment: In your second example, does the ternary operator work as a parameter because it gets evaluated as one expression? I really appreciate your detailed response (especially to such a beginner)!

Comment: I think the more important thing is, that the parser has problems to define, where the `if` belongs to. The ternary operator has less possibilties how it can be used and the parser has less problems to analyze the code.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is the precedence of those two operators. Consider the following:

```
options = {discount: false}
prexisting_value = "prexisting value"
```

using the first expression, you get this:

```
prexisting_value = options[:discount] ? "Does something if true" : nil
p prexisting_value
=> nil
```

using the second expression, you get this:

```
prexisting_value = "Do something if true" if options[:discount]
p prexisting_value
=> "prexisting_value"
```

this happens because the two examples are parsed differently (note the location of the parenthesis):

```
prexisting_value = (options[:discount] ? "Does something if true" : nil)
```

vs

```
(prexisting_value = "Do something if true") if options[:discount]
```